# Problema ao usar listen com where firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Olá, estou tentando filtrar os pedidos pela data atual, porém, quando tento usar o where na collection do firebase, o meu listen simplesmente para de funcionar. Não mandando nenhuma atualização nova para a lista.

De forma totalmente estranha, quando removo o where o listen volta a funcionar normalmente.

Alguém já passou pelo mesmo problema ou sabe uma possível solução?

**Listen firebase:**

```
Future<void> addPedidosListener() async{

    var now = new DateTime.now();
    var formatter = new DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
    String dataAtual = formatter.format(now);
    print(dataAtual);


    Pedido pedido;
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("pedidos")
        .doc("Kwdqc77luBnyPdS2AqD4")
        .collection("pedidos")
        .where("dataPedido", isEqualTo: dataAtual)
        .orderBy("numeroPedido", descending: false)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {

      snapshot.docChanges.forEach((change) {
        String pedidoId = change.doc.id;

        pedido = Pedido.fromDocumentSnapshot(change.doc);

        switch(change.type){
          case DocumentChangeType.added:
          //========== quando um pedido for adicionado ==========
          print('novo pedido');
            //pedidosModel.addPedido(pedido);
            pedidosModel.insertPedido(0, pedido);
            break;
          case DocumentChangeType.modified:
          //========== modificado ==========
            Pedido pedidoGlobal = Pedido.recuperarPedidoGlobal();
            if(pedidoGlobal != null && pedido.idPedido == pedidoGlobal.idPedido){
              Pedido.setarPedidoGlobal(pedido);
            }

            pedidosModel.listPedidos.indexWhere((element) {
              if(element.idPedido == pedido.idPedido){
                int index = pedidosModel.listPedidos.indexOf(element);
                pedidosModel.attPedido(index, pedido);
              }
              return  element.idPedido == pedido.idPedido;
            });
            break;
          case DocumentChangeType.removed:
          //========== removido ==========
            pedidosModel.removeWhere(pedidoId);
            break;
        }
      });

      //_sort();

    });
  }
```

**build:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final _pedidosBloc = BlocProvider.of<PedidosBloc>(context);

    return Observer(
      builder: (_){
        return ListView.builder(
          //reverse: true,
          itemCount: pedidosModel.listPedidos.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){

            return CardPedido(pedidosModel.listPedidos[index]);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

**mobx:**

```
part 'PedidosModel.g.dart';

class PedidosModel = _PedidosModel with _$PedidosModel;

abstract class _PedidosModel with Store{

  @observable
  ObservableList<Pedido> listPedidos = ObservableList();

  @action
  void addPedido(Pedido value){
    listPedidos.add(value);
  }

  @action
  void insertPedido(int index, Pedido value){
    //listPedidos.removeWhere((pedido) => pedido.idPedido == value.idPedido);
    listPedidos.insert(index, value);
  }

  @action
  void attPedido(int index, Pedido value){
    listPedidos.removeWhere((pedido) => pedido.idPedido == value.idPedido);
    listPedidos.insert(index, value);
  }

  @action
  void removeWhere(pedidoId){
    listPedidos.removeWhere((pedido) => pedido.idPedido == pedidoId);
  }

}
```

Comment: Alguns pontos para você rever... Ta esquisito a forma como você fez seu listen, será que não ficaria melhor fazer apenas `[...].collection("pedidos").where("dataPedido", isEqualTo: dataAtual)[...]`? E também veja no seu banco como está sendo salva a data, se não me engano o Firebase utiliza _Timestamp_, daí tu precisaria levar isso em consideração no momento de filtrar a data para retornar corretamente.

Comment: O listen tá correto, pois preciso do id da empresa antes. E sobre a data, quando filtro pela primeira vez ele traz realmente somente os itens da dataAtual, porém, ao atualizar algum dado o listen não é notificado automaticamente, o que deveria acontecer.

Comment: Andei pesquisando, pelo que vi somente é possível usar a condição where juntamente com a orderby caso os mesmos apontem para o mesmo campo. O desafio agora é descobrir como fazer esses filtros separadamente. fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58419902/where-and-orderby-filter-not-working-together-when-filtering-firebase-data

Comment: Meu amigo, não está faltando a criação de um índice lá no Firestore não? Vamos lá: quando vc usa "ordenação" com where, em alguns casos necessita de índices (como mencionado na doc do Firebase).